# Checkers: Is there a strategy to win with 2 pieces (one king) vs 3 pieces (one or two kings)?

Tags: checkers

Red ended up in this situation (see picture), and ended up losing. Is there a way for Red to win?

Mandatory jump is in effect.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean is there a way to win? What side where you playing? Winning or losing from that position is going to depend on the skill level of both players. Also if you include an idea of what you did it might help with the answer as well.

Comment: Re "*What do you mean is there a way to win?*", Is there a way to guarantee a win? Or conversely, can the the opponent force a loss? /// Re "*What side where you playing?*", Red, according to the title.

Comment: I think there are possibilities for red to win in this case but it is going to depend on the skill level of the other player and what moves they make. More information would still be very helpful.

Comment: @JoeW in chess etudes the skill of the players does not matter, it can be assumed that the other side plays perfectly. Can it also be reasonably assumed in this question?

Comment: From my understanding checkers is a solved game and perfect play will result in a draw so I would say it does matter.

Comment: We need to know the direction of play and who plays first.

Comment: @JoeW perfect play _from initial position_ will result in a draw, not from any position.

Comment: Which still means that perfect play would not have allowed for a losing situation so skill does matter

Comment: @JoeW Skill of players playing _from given position_ does not matter. Skill would matter for arriving into a given position but for an etude I'm comparing this with it's irrelevant, because those normally do not care about the history and only care if the position is winnable given perfect play of both parties.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh If skill doesn't matter why not provide an answer to the question? And as I said before given equal positions and perfect play the game is a draw. In order for it to be winnable either the positions have to be unequal or one side can't have perfect play.